# connect to ingres database from windows

Tags: jdbc, squirrel-sql, ingres, actian

How do I connect to a Ingres DB using SQuirrel SQL Client. I am getting the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to create connection. Check your URL.
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:136)
```

Is there a better way to connect to Ingres DB, version of this DB is Ingres SPARK Solaris version II 10.2.0

[image]

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, and include the actual JDBC url you used. Anonymize hostnames if necessary, but blanking the entire thing is not going to help if the error suggests "check your url".

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to create connection. Check your URL.
 at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:136)
 at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:167)
 at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$000(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
 at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$1.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:104)

Comment: The URL will typically be something like " jdbc:ingres://server:II7/dbname" (replace "II" with the relevant 2-character listen address on the target machine). Make sure the data access server is started on the server.